# Geolocation-based weather in Conky

Tags: conky, location, weather

### Automatically detect location in Conky

I travel to different places for work with my laptop. I would like to see the current weather for the place I am in. Is this possible?

There are `conky` configurations on Google for *Accuweather*, *WUnderground*, *NWS*, *Weather.com* and more, but all require you to find out some city id and hardcode it into `conky`.

Is there some service or trick or API to show the weather of the location I am in, without manually changing my `.conkyrc` every time I open my laptop?

### Technically this is possible

There is no GPS in my laptop and I have location services turned off, but still Google always seems to know exactly what city I am in. It's much more accurate than a geotrace of my public IP address, because that often traces me to the biggest city in a 200km radius.

### Ideas

So far I've found https://freegeoip.net/json/, but most often the region is not detected and the latitude/longitude is very imprecise (one decimal).

Comment: You need an API key for google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro